# ajax techniques

Tags: php, javascript, xml

How can I use ajax to periodically (every 10 seconds) retrieve data from an XML document?

Answer (score 4):

The same way as usual but with the addition of [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval)

Answer (score 1):

Ajax function can operate same as javascript function. You can use `setTimeout("func_name()",10000);` to call your ajax function every 10 seconds.

example:-

```
function ajaxFunc(){
   //-- ajax logic
   setTimeout("ajaxFunc()",10000);
}
```

Comment: That will call it after 10 seconds, not every 10 seconds — and pass functions to setTimeout. Passing a string to be evaled messes with scope, is hard to debug and is inefficient.

Comment: @David: This will call function on every 10 seconds; see my example.

Comment: you must set the timeout **before** the Ajax logic or it won't be 10 seconds, but slightly more.